# Is it bad practice for a Decorator Class to directly change the state of the innermost wrapped object

Tags: design-patterns, decorator

Normally by definition the Decorator Pattern attaches new behaviour to an object by using a chain of decorators on the decorated class. The pattern exploits the chain of decorators to the main decorated class to transform incoming and outgoing data to the decorated class.

Although there is a reference in every decorator class to the immediate successor there is no reference to the actual decorated class object (innermost class). So, there is no easy way that a decorator class could access or modify the decorated class's state (innermost class) unless this information is transferred in the chain of decorators (which is not very convinient).
This weird to me because the decorator pattern is considered the dynamic alternative of inheritance which allows this to happen. The subclasses can access and modify the state of the parent classes ( if they are not private ) however in the decorator pattern description this is not conviniently provided.

So the question is : Is it bad practice for a decorator to access the data in the innermost class in the chain ( decorated class )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page 175 of the GoF book,

> The decorator conforms to the interface of the component it decorates so that its presence is transparent to the component's clients... Transparency lets you nest decorators recursively...

So a Decorator is transparent not only to its clients but also to other Decorators. In other words, a Decorator does not know whether the component it wraps is another Decorator or not. There is no difference.

When a class is designed for inheritance, it chooses what to expose and what to keep private. When a Decorator is designed, it exposes everything that its wrapped component exposes, in order to provide the transparency referenced by the GoF.

So if an object provides access to modify its state, then any Decorator would provide the same access; "*this information is transferred in the chain of decorators*," but that is no different from any other decorated method.

> Is it bad practice for a decorator to access the data in the innermost class in the chain ( decorated class )?

If it, "conforms to the interface of the component it decorates," then this is unnecessary. If it doesn't conform, then it simply isn't a Decorator. Whether that is "good" or "bad" is entirely a matter of context and opinion.

Comment: And asking for opinion on SO is not allowed. Only fact based questions and answers.

Comment: So direct communication of the decorators with the decorated object ( innermost ) through a reference field in the decorator classes is not included in the Decorator Pattern. So as you said such a communication can be implemented using a chain of method calls from the decorator to the innermost class. Correct?

Comment: That is correct.